# What is a "wide character string" in C language?

Tags: c, string, widechar

I came across this in the book:

```
wscanf(L"%lf", &variable);
```

where the first parameter is of type of `wchar_t *`.

This s different from `scanf("%lf", &variable);` where the first parameter is of type `char *`.

So what is the difference than. I have never heard "wide character string" before. I have heard something called Raw String Literals which is printing the string as it is (no need for things like escape sequences) but that was not in C.

Comment: Start here http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: First parameter is actually of type `wchar_t []`, subtly different from `wchar_t *`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The *exact* nature of wide characters is (purposefully) left implementation defined.

When they first invented the concept of `wchar_t`, ISO 10646 and Unicode were still competing with each other (whereas they now, mostly cooperate). Rather than try to decree that an international character would be one or the other (or possibly something else entirely) they simply provided a type (and some functions) that the implementation could define to support international character sets as they chose.

Different implementations *have* exercised that potential for variation. For example, if you use Microsoft's compiler on Windows, `wchar_t` will be a 16-bit type holding UTF-16 Unicode (originally it held UCS-2 Unicode, but that's now officially obsolete).

On Linux, `wchar_t` will more often be a 32-bit type, holding UCS-4/UTF-32 encoded Unicode. Ports of gcc to at least some other operating systems do the same, though I've never tried to confirm that it's always the case.

There is, however, no guarantee of that. At least in theory an implementation on Linux could use 16 bits, or one on Windows could use 32 bits, or either one could decide to use 64 bits (though I'd be a little surprised to see that in reality).

In any case, the general idea of how things are *intended* to work, is that a single `wchar_t` is sufficient to represent a code point. For I/O, the data is intended to be converted from the external representation (whatever it is) into `wchar_t`s, which (is supposed to) make them relatively easy to manipulate. Then during output, they again get transformed into the encoding of your choice (which may be entirely different from the encoding you read).

Comment: what about other non-linux unix? also, isn't this a property of glibc rather than linux?

Comment: As I said, no, there's no guarantee of that: "in theory an implementation on Linux could use 16 bits". As far as non-Linux Unix goes, I haven't looked recently enough to comment intelligently.

Answer (score 11):

"Wide character string" is referring to the encoding of the characters in the string.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character):

> A wide character is a computer character datatype that generally has a
>   size greater than the traditional 8-bit character. The increased
>   datatype size allows for the use of larger coded character sets.

[UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) is one of the most commonly used wide character encodings.

Further, `wchar_t` is defined by [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367308%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as an `unsigned short(16-bit)` data object. This could be and is most likely a different definition in other operating systems or languages.

Taken from the Wikipedia article from the comment below:

> "The width of wchar_t is compiler-specific and can be as small as 8
>   bits. Consequently, programs that need to be portable across any C or
>   C++ compiler should not use wchar_t for storing Unicode text. The
>   wchar_t type is intended for storing compiler-defined wide characters,
>   which may be Unicode characters in some compilers."

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it's not portable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character

Comment: @quantum231, the wiki answer is really only true for MSFT. Read Jerry's answer and theJoel blog post