# C Programming - ascii for windows "unknown" characters

Tags: c, windows, console, ascii

I'm programming in windows, but in my C console some characters (like é, à, ã) are not recognizable. I would like to see how can I make widows interpret those chars as using unicode in the console or utf-8.

I would be glad for some enlightening.
Thank you very much

Comment: Strictly speaking, ASCII only defines characters 0 - 127. In this sense, your question is meaningless.

Comment: Can you show a simple example program or fragment you've tried that doesn't work?

Comment: Is this relevant (with no code I can't tell)?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287213/what-is-a-wide-character-string-in-c-language

Comment: I would guess that cmd.exe uses the same symbol table as good old DOS. Meaning you'll have 7-bit ASCII and then a non-standard "extended ASCII" on top of that, such as the tables in [this link](http://www.asciitable.com/). "Extended ASCII" is not compatible with UTF-8.

Comment: @Bathsheba, some people use "ascii" when they really mean "8-bit". My command window uses code page 437 by default, which has many accented characters but in different positions than they are in ISO/IEC-8859-1 (which was used for the first 256 codepoints of Unicode).

Answer (score 1):

By console do you mean `cmd.exe`? It doesn't handle Unicode well, but you can get it to display "ANSI" characters by changing the display font to **Lucida Console** and changing the code page from "OEM" to "ANSI." By the choice of characters you seem to be Western European, so try giving this command before running your application:

```
chcp 1252
```

If you want to try your luck with UTF-8 output use `chcp 65001` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although I completely agree with **Joni**'s answer, I think it can be added a detail:

Since **Telmo Vaz** asked about how to solve this problem for **C** programs, we can consider the alternative of adding a system command inside the code:

```
  #include <stdlib.h>   // To use the function system();
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void) {
      system("CHCP 1252");

      printf("Now accents are right: áéíüñÇ  \n");
      return 0;
  }
```

**EDIT** It is a good idea to do some experiments with codepages. Check the following table for information (under Windows):

[Windows Codepages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Have you checked if this really works? I think `chcp` is a builtin command, not an external program that can be executed through `system`.

Comment: @Joni This works, I used it thousands of times since I am a Spanish speaker.