# how to create custom byte level datatype?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, types

I'd like to know how to create my own byte level datatype (like int, short, long, etc.). I know some will ask "Why!!? this is crazy!!" let's say I don't wanna use classes or structs. And I wanna know how to create that kind of datatype for C/C++ even if I have to use asm code for that (which I guess I'll have to use). Or is there a book that could help?

Can anyone please help? thank you.

Comment: The only way to 'create' these data types is to re-write/write a c++/c compiler in a way that parses and stores your new types using assembly instructions. I would say get a good book on compilers and grab the source for GCC.

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible. Please explain better what you're trying to achieve and somebody may be able to help you...

Comment: Sounds like a typical [X-Y Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you exclude all the methods C and C++ give you to create new types then you can't create new types.

It's simple with a class:

Make a class that has some sort of storage. If you insist on doing everything manually then just make this an array of bytes. Overload all the operators you want to support.

```
class my_datatype
{
public:
   my_datatype();
   // overload operators
private:
   uint8_t[sizeof_my_datatype] data;
};
```

Other than classes and structs, the only way to "make" a new datatype in C and C++ is a `typedef`. That's nothing more than an alias, though.

Comment: OP does not want to use classes or structs, but OP doesn't really seem to know what s/he wants...

Comment: the problem here is I don't think this would work for C only compiler

Comment: You said c++ as well.

Comment: yes I said C++ as well but I meant if it works on C it should work on C++ just like int, double,etc. which is not the case for class

Comment: If you exclude all the methods C and C++ give you to create new types then you can't create new types.

Comment: @R.. whell i do know wtha i want ;) .. I'd like to create my own datatype  which consist of a two 8-bits bytes in which I can store positive number only from 0 to (2^16)-1 even though what I actually want to store in it are character

Comment: @PaikuHan: Why don't you want to use `uint16_t`?

Comment: I.e. you want to recreate `uint16_t`.

Comment: @Adam there still is asm left to write in a c source. I guess this is how int, char, long and all the other were created??

Comment: You can write assembly all you want but that won't create a datatype that is exposed to other C code. You have to put assembly inside a function which will look like any other C function.

Comment: No, it's not. `int`, `char`, and `long` are part of the language. They are neither implemented in C nor in asm, but as part of the compiler's task of translating the C program to whatever final form it will be run in.

Comment: Oh! ok then I guess that's it I have to create a uint16_t

Comment: You describe a "wide character". I.e. a unicode character. Believe me, you're far from the first person do do this.

Comment: @Adam: Huh? I see no indication that this problem has anything to do with Unicode or storing characters; if it did, a 16-bit type would be inappropriate, as Unicode is 21-bit.

Comment: He says "what I actually want to store in it are character". So either it's UTF-16 or a whole 'nother reinvention of the wheel.

Comment: @Adam you got it right. that's what I exactly want but the problem here is that C does not support operator overload.

Comment: Just use wide characters as supplied by your platform. See here for an overview: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11287282/321772

Comment: @R.. 16-bit is the definition given by wikipedia maybe I misunderstood

Comment: I find that in the western world UTF-8 is the most common, because it only uses extra bytes for the few characters not in ASCII. The UTF-16 and 32 are mainly going to be used in countries where every character is wide (eg. Chinese), or in places where you need a fixed length per character.