# what is difference between character wide 1 and e.g 6

Tags: c

Im learning from start C basic.And i dont understand character wide.When i change it nothing visual happens,so i dont know what is purpose of this

I was researching and at first i discovered that its not string length but 
character datatype,but more info i wasnt able to find

```
 main()
 {
     float farh, celsium ;
     int lower, upper, step;

     lower = 0;
     upper = 300;
     step = 20;

     farh = lower;
     while(farh <= upper) {
         celsium = (5.0/9.0) * (farh - 32.0);
         printf( "%5.2f %5.2f\n",farh, celsium);
         farh = farh + step;
     }
 }
```

output is temperature in celsuim and fahrenheit (0.000000 -17.777779)

in the code above

```
%5.2f
```

represent each argument to be alerted with character wide at least 5 and with 2 numbers after decimal point. But what changes if i write 2, 6 or other number instead of 5?

Comment: Be aware that "wide characters" in C don't refer to what you're presently asking about. Instead, it has to do with Unicode 16-bits encoded characters. Check out this entry : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287213/what-is-a-wide-character-string-in-c-language

Answer (score 0):

```
 printf("%5.2f\n", 3.223467856);
```

**Consider the above statement:**

printing with %5.2f will generate : _3.22 ( the symbol _ represents a blank space at the beginning, **won't be printed in console**)

`5:` The number will occupy space of 5 character wide. (.) dot occupies 1 char space too)

`2:` The number will occupy 2 digits after decimal point(.)

```
printf("%6.2f\n", 3.223467856);
```

printing with %6.2f will generate : __3.22

```
printf("%6.3f\n", 3.223467856);
```

printing with %6.2f will generate : _3.223

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the program (with some cleanup):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void) {
        int const lower_limit = 0;
        int const upper_limit = 300;
        int const step = 20;

        float fahrenheit = lower_limit;
        while (fahrenheit <= upper_limit) {
            float const celsius = (5.0f / 9.0f) * (fahrenheit - 32.0f);
            printf("%9.6f\t%10.6f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
            fahrenheit += step;
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

You'll see the difference between `%9.6f` and `%10.6f` which should show something like:

```
 0.000000   -17.777779
20.000000    -6.666667
40.000000     4.444445
60.000000    15.555556
80.000000    26.666668
100.000000   37.777779
120.000000   48.888893
140.000000   60.000004
160.000000   71.111115
180.000000   82.222229
200.000000   93.333336
220.000000  104.444450
240.000000  115.555557
260.000000  126.666672
280.000000  137.777786
300.000000  148.888901
```

You see a difference in behaviour when `fahrenheit` goes from `0` to `20` vs from `80` to `100`.