# c++ winapi code blocks works and visual studio community not

Tags: c++, winapi

In code blocks, it works without any errors. But in Visual Studio, it says:

> C++ argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type LPCWSTR

This is my code:

```cpp
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
    #define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
#endif
#include <windows.h>
    
    
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE hPrev,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow){
    
    int s =  MessageBox(NULL,"Hi This is my First c++ GUI","Win32 API Say:",6);
    if(s == 10){
        MessageBox(NULL,"Hi This is my First c++ GUI","Win32 API Say:",6);
    }else if(s == 11){
        MessageBox(NULL,"Yes GO On","Win32 API Say:",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }else{
        MessageBox(NULL,"GoodBey !!","Win32 API Say:",MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *MessageBox**W*** wait *PC**W**STR* strings but you pass *PCSTR*

Comment: Change `"Hi This is my First c++ GUI","Win32 API Say:"` to `L"Hi This is my First c++ GUI","Win32 API Say:"` and do similar to the rest.

Comment: ***but in in visual studio it says C++ argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type LPCWSTR*** Visual Studio is correct. You passed a narrow string when it required a wide string.

Comment: Thank you Guys <3 you helped me to understand the issue correctly , i should stop using code blocks due to it's weak compiler

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287213/what-is-a-wide-character-string-in-c-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287213/what-is-a-wide-character-string-in-c-language)

Comment: *"i should stop using code blocks due to it's weak compiler"* - The issue wasn't caused by the compiler. It was caused by the default project settings.

Comment: In VS, you can also modify the properties->Advanced->Character Set to change the character set to apply the function you want to match by default (MessageBoxA or MessageBoxW).Because your VS is set to "Use Unicode Character Set" by default, it corresponds to the MessageBoxW function when mapping, and the character set of codeblocks is different, and the MessageBoxA function is mapped, and the parameter types they need are different.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `TCHAR` version of `MessageBox()`, which is actually a preprocessor macro that maps to either `MessageBoxW()` or `MessageBoxA()` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.

In case of CodeBlocks, it works if `UNICODE` is not defined, so `MessageBox()` maps to `MessageBoxA()`, which expects `LPCSTR` (`const char *`) strings as input.  You are passing in `char`-based string literals, so all is good.

In case of Visual Studio, is fails if `UNICODE` is defined, so `MessageBox()` maps to `MessageBoxW()`, which expects `LPCWSTR` (`const wchar_t *`) strings as input.  Since you are passing in `char`-based string literals, and `char*` is not implicitly convertible to `wchar_t*`, hence the error.

If you are going to continue using `TCHAR` functionality <sup>1</sup>, you should wrap your string literals in the [`TEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) preprocessor macro to make them use the same character encoding that `MessageBox()` (or any other `TCHAR` based API) expects, based on compiler settings.

<sup>1: you really should not rely on `TCHAR` in modern code. It exists only for backwards compatibility with legacy code that predates Microsoft's push to get Win9x/ME apps migrated to Unicode on NT4+/Win2K/XP.  `TCHAR` was invented to help such code migrate from ANSI `char` strings to Unicode `wchar_t` strings.</sup>

Also, you should not be relying on ["magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), either.  It makes the code harder to read and understand.  Use pre-defined named constants instead.  You are already doing that for `MB_ICONINFORMATION` and `MB_OK` in your 3rd and 4th calls to `MessageBox()`, but you are using numeric literals instead for the 1st and 2nd calls to `MessageBox()`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
    #define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
#endif
#include <windows.h>
    
    
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE hPrev,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow){
    
    int s =  MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Hi This is my First c++ GUI"), TEXT("Win32 API Say:"), MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE);
    if(s == IDTRYAGAIN){
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Hi This is my First c++ GUI"), TEXT("Win32 API Say:"), MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE);
    }else if(s == IDCONTINUE){
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Yes GO On"), TEXT("Win32 API Say:"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }else{
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("GoodBey !!"), TEXT("Win32 API Say:"), MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That said, you should not rely on `TCHAR` APIs at all, and instead just call `MessageBoxA()` or `MessageBoxW()` (or other narrow/wide APIs) directly as needed, eg:

```cpp
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
    #define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
#endif
#include <windows.h>
    
    
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE hPrev,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow){
    
    int s =  MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hi This is my First c++ GUI", "Win32 API Say:", MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE);
    if(s == IDTRYAGAIN){
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hi This is my First c++ GUI", "Win32 API Say:", MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE);
    }else if(s == IDCONTINUE){
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Yes GO On", "Win32 API Say:", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }else{
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "GoodBey !!", "Win32 API Say:", MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
    #define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
#endif
#include <windows.h>
    
    
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE hPrev,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow){
    
    int s =  MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Hi This is my First c++ GUI", L"Win32 API Say:", MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE);
    if(s == IDTRYAGAIN){
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Hi This is my First c++ GUI", L"Win32 API Say:", MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE);
    }else if(s == IDCONTINUE){
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Yes GO On", L"Win32 API Say:", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }else{
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"GoodBey !!", L"Win32 API Say:", MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All versions of Windows NT (3.1 and up) used Unicode. Windows 2000 (NT 5.0) introduced UTF-16 support, not Unicode as a whole, as footnote 1 suggests.